# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() getting no result or errors in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have written and test my php code (not WordPress) it works well. But it doesn't work in WordPress.
here's my snippet code (got error result):

```
function totalTrackLenght($tracklenght){
    global $row, $data, $tracklenght;
    foreach ($data->results as $row) {
        if(!empty($row->trackTimeMillis)){
            $tracklenght += $row->trackTimeMillis;
        }
    }
    return $tracklenght;
}
```

php file to display the result:

```
<li class="total-tr-lenght"><?php nextFunction(); ?></li>
```

I change `foreach ($data->results as $row)` to `foreach ((array)$data->results as $row)` is getting no result.

The JSON data obtained from https://itunes.apple.com/us/lookup?id=1434446667&entity=song

Comment: Dump the result of $data->results. Probably it is not a iterable object / array.

Comment: You get a file named 1.txt back not a json string.

Comment: @Timo002 here's the output http://pasted.co/68a611d8

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your json is not stored as an associative array, if you're processing json with json_decode method, you should set second parameter as true - returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

```
$data = json_decode($json, true)
```

More info about [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: should I change to foreach ($data['results'] as $row) ?

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: getting the same result as above

Comment: then check if $data is initialized correctly

Comment: yes, it is. I put the code above in the function.php file, I'm stuck wih Wordpress. Whereas it works correctly in one single php file